# Powershell Script for adding users to AD

Tags: powershell, csv, windows-server-2012-r2

Hi I've just resently started to use powershell on my server. Though when I run the script I get the error:

```
New-ADUser : Unable to find a default server with Active Directory Web Services running.
At C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Powerwhell Script, H1 case.ps1:6 char:1
+ New-ADUser -name $_."fornavn" 
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [New-ADUser], ADServerDownException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:1355,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.NewADUser
```

I have attached the script and my .csv file. Hope any of you can help me figuring it out.

(Don't worry about the information, it's for a school assignment)

[Script](http://pastebin.com/80evbkSE)

[.csv file](http://pastebin.com/k7NVKv6K)

Comment: Are you posting real production data to random strangers in Internet?

Comment: No ofcourse not, don't worry :P It's for a school assignment

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your script can not find the domain control on your domain. Simply use the `-Server` parameter and give it the Full Qualified Domain Name or IP of the domain control.

```
New-ADUser -Server "ServerName.Domain.com"
```

If this doesn't work you might not have `Active Directory Management Gateway Service` installed on your domain control ([Download Here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=2852)). With Windows server 2012 R2 make sure you have the following feature installed.

[image]

The headers warning you are seeing is because `Import-Csv` is unable to get the headings from your CSV file for some reason, and replaces the header name with `H1`,`H2` ... `Hx`. For example:

```
fornavn   efternavn  H1     beskrivelse, ...
-------   ---------  -----  -----------
Keld      Bruun      KB     Adm.Ledergruppe, ...
```

You can get round this you can giving `Import-Csv` the names of your columns via the `-Header` parameter. Note that these do not have to be the same as the ones in the `CSV`, as the new column headers will overwrite the `CSV`.

```
Import-Csv "C:\H1, Powershell.csv" -Header 'fornavn','efternavn','forkortelse','beskrivelse','email','brugernavn','kode','kontor','fuldnavn'
```

Comment: PS C:\Users\Administrator> C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Powerwhell Script, H1 case.ps1
WARNING: One or more headers were not specified. Default names starting with "H" have been used in place of any missing headers.
cmdlet New-ADUser at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Name:

Comment: I tried with the domain and server name, but it returns the message above. And I cant download, the Active Directory Management Gateway Service, its for the windows server 2003/2008. And I'm using 2012 R2 (forgot to mention)

Comment: After installing the Remote Server Administration Tools, I get this message: WARNING: One or more headers were not specified. Default names starting with "H" have been used in place of any missing headers.
New-ADUser : The directory service has exhausted the pool of relative identifiers.

Comment: Okay. I will try it over the weekend.  Then I'll return with the results.

Comment: Okay so I think I've found the problem. But not sure how to fix it. If I remove '$_.' form the first line where I write **New-ADUser -name $_."fornavn"** it says it cant find the argument. But if I remove the first part '$_.' it creates the user, with the name **fornavn** . I dunno if this could be the problem? But maybe it cant find the part in the csv file that I point it towards?

Comment: You shouldn't need the double quotes `"` in `$_."fornavn"`, so `$_.fornavn`.